# How can i be sure that my typeof is really working?

Tags: javascript, typeof

(ultra-Junior dev here)

I have these code.. using typeof to validate if the client puts a string or not.. Otherwise will not proced with the task and will send an error 400... The things is that with my dev-Front colegue.. He is putting a string in the username and he is having a 400 error.

-- if there is another method to check is the input is a string or not.??

its a big validator checking at the same time other type of inputs.. so maybe your answer could impact all the code.

Thanks

could someone explain why

```
 function tappingValidator(req, res, next) {
  if (typeof req.body.username !== "string") {
    const msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: "username has to be a string" });
    const err = new Error(msg);
    err.statusCode = 400;
    return next(err);
  }};
```

Comment: My guess is that `req.body.username` is undefined.

Comment: Do you know what `req.body.username` outputs? log that and see what it is

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to your codebase

```js
function isString(arg) {
   return typeof arg === 'string' || arg instanceof String
}
```

and then use it in if statement like this:

```js
if(!isString(req.body.username)) {
   // it is not a string

   // ...
}
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be the solution. You are adding an additional check to see whether an identifier references an object that has `String.prototype` on its prototype chain, which will capture a vanishingly small number (probably zero) of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! interesting idea. i don't about the instanceof but it could be interesting to adapt the validator with these idea.. i will keep it in mind :.. And the problem was comming from the front.. They were sending an empty object so there it was always a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any sequence of characters, including a sequence of pure digits, is a string. It's context and/or syntax that makes the difference between what's a number and what's a string.

```
const a = 123;
const b = '123';
console.log(typeof a); // displays "number"
console.log(typeof b); // display "string"
```

`req.body.username` is probably a string data type (something coming from a web form) no matter what the content of that string is.

If you want to make sure the string doesn't start with a digit, this regular expression test will work:

```
  if (/^[\d]/.test(req.body.username)) {
    const msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: "username shouldn't start with a digit" });
```

There are other tests if you merely wanted to rule out something purely numeric, but that is allowed to start with a digit.